# Reversing the vowels in a String

Tags: java, beginner, strings, interview-questions, complexity

> > Given a string, reverse only the vowels present in it and print the
> >     resulting string.
> >
> > **Input:**
>
> First line of the input file contains an integer **T** denoting the
>   number of test cases. Then **T** test cases follow. Each test case has a
>   single line containing a string.
>
> > **Output:**
>
> Corresponding to each test case, output the string with vowels
>    reversed.
>
> > Example:
> >
> > **Input:**
> >
> > 4
> >
> > geeksforgeeks
> >
> > practice
> >
> > wannacry
> >
> > ransomware
> >
> > **Output:**
> >
> > geeksforgeeks
> >
> > prectica
> >
> > wannacry
> >
> > rensamwora

My approach:

```
/*package whatever //do not write package name here */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class GFG {

    private static String reverseVowels (String str) {

        List <Character>vowels = new ArrayList <>();
        vowels.add('a');
        vowels.add('e');
        vowels.add('i');
        vowels.add('o');
        vowels.add('u');

        List <Character>values = new ArrayList <>();
        List <Integer>keys = new ArrayList <>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (vowels.contains(str.charAt(i))) {
                keys.add(i);
                values.add(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str);

        Collections.reverse(values);
        int count = 0;

        for (Integer num : keys) {
            sb.replace(num.intValue(),num.intValue() + 1,String.valueOf(values.get(count)));
            count++;
        }


        return sb.toString();

    } 

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int numTests = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++) {
            String str = sc.next();
            System.out.println(reverseVowels(str));
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following questions about my code:

1) How can I further improve my approach?

2) Is there a better way to solve this question?

3) Are there any grave code violations that I have committed?

4) Can space and time complexity be further improved?

My time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is also O(n) currently.

[Reference](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reversing-the-vowels/0/?track=SP-Strings)

Answer (score 2):

- Time complexity is \$O(n)\$ indeed. Since every input character must be inspected, this asymptotic is impossible to improve. However, it is possible to improve the constant. See below.
- Space complexity is \$O(n)\$ indeed. However, it is possible to solve the problem is \$O(1)\$. Consider two iterators, one running left to right, and another running right to left. As long as the first iterator points a consonant, print it. As soon as it hits a vowel, scan the second iterator (right to left) until it finds a vowel, and print *that* vowel. Notice that this approach also doesn't need `values` and `keys` - and hence doesn't need to build them. This is how time complexity is also improved.
- The line

  ```
  sb.replace(num.intValue(),num.intValue() + 1,String.valueOf(values.get(count)));
  ```

  is very hard to read. It is even harder to prove that it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @vnp. I had added **.intValue()** as a precautionary measure against the compiler.